How to hide participant at bottom of sequence diagram in mermaid
My question is how to draw a sequence diagram in mermaid with participants only showing at the top. The default behaviour seems to be to draw them at both top and bottom which might be not needed when having small diagrams. My example code below.
sequenceDiagram
A->>B: Message 1
B->>C: Message 2


The mermaid online doc explains that a parameter mirrorActors: false can deactivate the bottom part.  However I'm not a mermaid specialist, and did not manage to add this config JSON in the drawing command.  I suppose this can be done somehow in the API or in a config file at start of the instance...

I tried to enter that into the mermaid.live editor, but I had no success with that

Yes, that's what I meant with "I did not manage to add this config ... drawing command". I think this requires some kind of special accesses to the server. Maybe some expert around knows it, and help us to connect the dots

This is possible using frontmatter config, but it is not perfect, as it seems to extend the lifelines far down the render container
Live editor
---
title: Hello Title
config:
  mirrorActors: false
---

sequenceDiagram
A->>B: Message 1
B->>C: Message 2


If you're using Notion or GitLab, the representation is a bit different. Add this to the top of the document:
%%{init: { 'sequence': {'mirrorActors':false} } }%%

